# Constraining movement of a node to a single axis

Tags: cytoscape.js

Using [Cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/), how can I constrain movement of a node to a single (i.e. either the x or y) axis?  I'd like to be able to make it so a node can only be dragged vertically or horizontally, but not both.  In other words, I'd like to lock a node, but only on a single axis.  I'm not sure if this is possible, and wasn't able to find anything in the documentation that mentioned this specifically, so I figured I'd ask.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [automove](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-automove) extension, which lets you set whatever restrictions on node positioning that you like.  Constraining the x value is as easy as passing a `(x, y) => { return { xConst, y }; }` function to the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with a way to approximate the result that I wanted by listening for each node's `free` event, and setting its position to what I needed it to be.  This doesn't restrict *dragging* of nodes to a single axis, but it does restrict *dropping* of nodes to a single axis, if that makes sense.

Here is the Cytoscape.js description of the `free` event:

> free : when an element is freed (i.e. let go from being grabbed)

from: http://js.cytoscape.org/#events/collection-events